# Using proper virtualenv and flake8 config with Flycheck

Tags: python, emacs, flycheck

How can I use configured virtualenv and flake8 settings file (setup.cfg in root of project), for flycheck in emacs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I spent some time to find right solution and decided to implement my own:

[flycheck-local-flake8](https://github.com/rmuslimov/flycheck-local-flake8)

This is plugin for flycheck-flake8 checker, simply uses flake8 from required virtualenv and setup.cfg from root of the python project.

Answer (score 2):

There are a number of plugins for working with virtualenvs. For example, with [`pyvenv`](https://github.com/jorgenschaefer/pyvenv) installed I can use the `pyvenv-workon` command to select a virtualenv from `$WORKON_HOME`.

[`virtualenvwrapper`](https://github.com/porterjamesj/virtualenvwrapper.el) and [`python-environment`](https://github.com/tkf/emacs-python-environment) provide similar support, and all three are available on MELPA.

Flycheck has an option [`flycheck-flake8rc`](http://flycheck.readthedocs.org/en/latest/guide/languages.html#el.variable.flycheck-flake8rc):

> Configuration file for `` `python-flake8' ``.

If you have per-project configuration files, it might be easiest to create [`.dir-locals.el`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Directory-Variables.html) files in the root of each project that sets `flycheck-flake8rc` to the appropriate value, e.g.

```
((python-mode
  (flycheck-flake8rc . "/path/to/setup.cfg")))
```

I would advise not tracking `.dir-locals.el` in whatever version control system you are using, though of course that is up to you.

Comment: what is "/path/to/setup.cfg" this file? what should it contain?

Comment: @silgon, it's a flake8 configuration file. See http://flake8.readthedocs.org/en/latest/config.html.

Comment: Thanks for the superfast answer. Nevertheless, in the configuration there's no part to insert the virtualenv path. Are there more settings?

Comment: @silgon, the configuration file is for the flake8 portion of the question. The virtualenv portion is answered in the first two paragraphs of my answer.